# How to Implement / Link Run Keeper API in Android using Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, api, webviewclient

I want to use run keeper API in my Code as I am developing Application which will track walking distance etc . This can be done by using Run Keeper API.
    During registering my app, it ask me to enter post call back URL , I don't know from where to get The CALL BACK URL :(

Here is the code where I am stuck.

```
package com.example.testapp;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button button;
    private WebView webView;

    private final static String CLIENT_ID = "b25ef732fdea4fc1a5d59036f05cfad0";
    private final static String CLIENT_SECRET = "741a1216e5f14c38b5768840d6720d2c";
    private final static String CALLBACK_URL = "";

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Force to login on every launch.
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.removeAllCookie();

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        getAuthorizationCode();
    }

    private void getAuthorizationCode() {
        String authorizationUrl = "https://runkeeper.com/apps/authorize";
        authorizationUrl = String.format(authorizationUrl, CLIENT_ID,CALLBACK_URL);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Milestone 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (url.startsWith(CALLBACK_URL)) {
                    final String authCode = Uri.parse(url).getQueryParameter("code");
                    webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    getAccessToken(authCode);
                    return true;
                }

                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
        });

        webView.loadUrl(authorizationUrl);
    }

    private void getAccessToken(String authCode) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Milestone 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String accessTokenUrl = "https://runkeeper.com/apps/token";
        final String finalUrl = String.format(accessTokenUrl, authCode,CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
        Thread networkThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(finalUrl);

                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

                    String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(response
                            .getEntity());
                    final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);

                    String accessToken = json.getString("access_token");
                    getTotalDistance(accessToken);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    displayToast("Exception occured:(");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    resetUi();
                }

            }
        });

        networkThread.start();
    }

    private void getTotalDistance(String accessToken) {
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://api.runkeeper.com/user/");

            get.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            get.addHeader("Accept", "*/*");

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);

            String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
            findTotalWalkingDistance(jsonArray);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            displayToast("Exception occured:(");
            e.printStackTrace();
            resetUi();
        }
    }

    private void findTotalWalkingDistance(JSONArray arrayOfRecords) {
        try {
            // Each record has activity_type and array of statistics. Traverse
            // to activity_type = Walking
            for (int ii = 0; ii < arrayOfRecords.length(); ii++) {
                JSONObject statObject = (JSONObject) arrayOfRecords.get(ii);
                if ("Walking".equalsIgnoreCase(statObject
                        .getString("activity_type"))) {
                    // Each activity_type has array of stats, navigate to
                    // "Overall" statistic to find the total distance walked.
                    JSONArray walkingStats = statObject.getJSONArray("stats");
                    for (int jj = 0; jj < walkingStats.length(); jj++) {
                        JSONObject iWalkingStat = (JSONObject) walkingStats
                                .get(jj);
                        if ("Overall".equalsIgnoreCase(iWalkingStat
                                .getString("stat_type"))) {
                            long totalWalkingDistanceMeters = iWalkingStat
                                    .getLong("value");
                            double totalWalkingDistanceMiles = totalWalkingDistanceMeters * 0.00062137;
                            displayTotalWalkingDistance(totalWalkingDistanceMiles);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            displayToast("Something went wrong!!!");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            displayToast("Exception occured:(");
            e.printStackTrace();
            resetUi();
        }
    }

    private void resetUi() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }

    private void displayTotalWalkingDistance(double totalWalkingDistanceMiles) {
        final String milesWalkedMessage = (totalWalkingDistanceMiles < 1) ? "0 miles?, You get no respect, Start walking already!!!"
                : String.format("Cool, You have walked %.2f miles so far.",
                        totalWalkingDistanceMiles);

        displayToast(milesWalkedMessage);
        resetUi();
    }

    private void displayToast(final String message) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this Runkeeper CallBack Hope it works for you. All the best.

```
com.example.runkeeperapi://RunKeeperIsCallingBack"
```